# How to remove datetimes in list based on minutes?

Tags: python, list, loops, datetime

We are working with Python 3, where we have a list of datetimes, which looks like this:

```
first_datetime = {2019-08-08 14:00:00, 2019-08-08 14:10:00, 2019-08-08 14:20:00, 2019-08-08 14:30:00, 2019-08-08 14:40:00, 2019-08-08 14:50:00, 2019-08-08 15:00:00}
```

What we want is to only append datetimes, where minutes in datetime is either 00, 20 or 40, into a new list.

Therefore above list should look like:

```
new_datetime_list = {2019-08-08 14:00:00, 2019-08-08 14:20:00, 2019-08-08 14:40:00, 2019-08-08 15:00:00}
```

Our program looks like following:

```
for i in range(len(first_datetime)):
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_datetime[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if time != x:
        new_datetime_list.append(first_datetime[i])
```

We imagine that we could do something like:

```
for i in range(len(first_datetime)):
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_datetime[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if time != x and time != CAN'T CONTAIN 10, 30, 50 IN MINUTES:
        new_datetime_list.append(first_datetime[i])
```

Although we dont know how to to the above, hence we are posting this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the minutes using `time.minute in [0, 20, 40]`, so your snippet of code could look like

```py
for i in range(len(first_datetime)):
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_datetime[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if time != x and time.minute in [0, 20, 40]:
        new_datetime_list.append(first_datetime[i])
```

(I have kept the `time != x` condition, not sure if you need it for something else you didn't mention)
btw you can simplify the way you iterate through the array without using indexes like this:

```py
for str_datetime in first_datetime:
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if time != x and time.minute in [0, 20, 40]:
        new_datetime_list.append(str_datetime)
```

Comment: Yes, we are using 'time != x' for another calculation. This works like a charm, and your improvement is a big bonus. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `minute` operator from datetime:

```
import datetime
first_datetime = ['2019-08-08 14:00:00', '2019-08-08 14:10:00', '2019-08-08 14:20:00', '2019-08-08 14:30:00', '2019-08-08 14:40:00', '2019-08-08 14:50:00', '2019-08-08 15:00:00']
new_datetime_list = []

for i in first_datetime:
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').minute
    if (time == 20) | (time == 40) | (time == 0):
        new_datetime_list.append(i)
```

Output (`print(new_datetime_list)`):

```
['2019-08-08 14:00:00', '2019-08-08 14:20:00', '2019-08-08 14:40:00', '2019-08-08 15:00:00']
```